# How can I use "IN" operator into variable or parameter then use into query of ADO.NET Source SSIS

Tags: sql, ssis, etl, ssis-2012

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT ZPRESUPUESTO,DWERK  FROM ZTSD_PRESPZA_WF WHERE MANDT = 720 AND ZVERSION = 'A'
```

That I want to do is to add something like

```
 SELECT ZPRESUPUESTO,DWERK  FROM ZTSD_PRESPZA_WF WHERE MANDT = 720 AND ZVERSION = 'A' AND DWERK IN(2001,2002,2003,2004)
```

How can I do that? Regards

Try:[image]

Comment: have you tried it? your syntax looks right

Comment: Yes But I get error, I upload it to my question @maSTAShuFu

Comment: can you run your sql sql statement in sql studio?

Comment: the other way is use between... DWERK between 2001 and 2004

Comment: No I can´t run with SQL because my conn is from SAP system

Answer (score 0):

use between instead of IN

```
DWERK between 2001 and 2004
```

try this

```
DWERK IN ('2001','2004')
```

Comment: But I want to be able for the future add another like 1001, I can´t use between

Comment: think sap interprets IN as string

Comment: can you try a different string field and use IN if that's going to work

Comment: as previously mentioned can you please try a different string field and use IN

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable to hold your list of values with each value separated by a comma. Then add an expression to the SQLCommand of your SQL Source with the following expression:

```
"SELECT 
  ZPRESUPUESTO
  ,DWERK  
FROM ZTSD_PRESPZA_WF 
WHERE MANDT = 720 
  AND ZVERSION = 'A' 
  AND DWERK IN(" + [User::your_variable] + ")"
```